# Installing Webmin - dpkg: unable to access dpkg status area

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, deb, dpkg, webmin

I was able to install webmin before the openssl update on Amazon, but I had to uninstall it. I then had the openssl update when I received the email from Amazon. Today, I am trying to install webmin again:

```
sudo wget http://www.webmin.com/download/deb/webmin-current.deb
sudo dpkg -i webmin-current.deb
```

But then this error shows up:

```
dpkg: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory
```

I have been able to install dpkg:

```
sudo yum install dpkg
```

-because earlier I was having this error: sudo dpkg command not found

I have been able to enter sudo yum update and sudo yum upgrade, but I'm still having the error while trying to install the webmin-current.deb

I have been googling all day and I haven't found a solution to my problem yet. Please help.

Comment: Usually yum is a package tool for Red Hat based distro, while dpkg and apt is used for Ubuntu and debian. Are you sure you use an Ubuntu system? What is the content of /etc/issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude ! You are installing a `deb` package using `yum`.  You should use an `rpm` package for `yum` (RedHat/CentOS/Amazon Linux).

You should use a `deb` package if your distro is Debian or Ubuntu.

You want:

```
wget http://download.webmin.com/download/yum/webmin-1.680-1.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ihv webmin-1.680-1.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks! I did select Ubuntu Server 12.04 on Amazon EC2. So I searched how to install for Ubuntu. Kind of confusing for me since I don't have any tech background at all. Still trying to understand :)